# Convert perspective image to topview

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm having a camera image and it's homography matrix. The camera image is of a road . I would like to convert that video image into a top view image.

I already have the homography matrix

```
h = np.array([ 0.859283348783, -11.6919721588, 1606.83612681, 0.648017266624, -2.70283366148, -9.14157643688, 0.000363253304864, -0.00846479846914, 1])
```

What I do is :

```
while (cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        t1 = time.time()

        img = pipeline(frame, car_tracker,ped_tracker, det)

        h = np.array([ 0.859283348783, -11.6919721588, 1606.83612681, 0.648017266624, -2.70283366148, -9.14157643688, 0.000363253304864, -0.00846479846914, 1])

        matrix = np.reshape(h, (3, 3))
        dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix,img.shape[1::-1])
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Frame', dst)
        #writer.write(img)
        # Press Q on keyboard to  exit

        cv2.waitKey(1)

    # Break the loop
```

but I do get a distored image, not even a top view or anything, just a black image.

[image]

Here is an input image that can be tested

[image]

Comment: _I would like to convert that video image into a top view image._ Like taken from a camera "hanging" above the street looking downwards onto the street? You do know, that won't work?

Comment: No that its not the issue, I want to explain that I need a bird eye view..

Comment: @HansHirse I want actually to skew the image

Comment: It looks like the homography matrix is not correct, how did you calculate it? You can probably calculate it using he gray container on the right or the roof of the car. Maybe it is the size of the destination image with this homography? you can try using it doubled... as you can see there is something in the bottom right...maybe it is being translated more than expected

Comment: @api55 Can you post an answer with detailed directions to the calculations of homography matrix ?

Comment: Here is a top down view of the crosswalk in the center of the image: https://imgur.com/a/fQaCcN9